# C Segmentation fault when implementing insertiong of a node in a binary tree

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I try to implement a binary tree in C with only one operation for the moment - insertion of a node to the tree. The problem I am facing is that I have a segmentation fault. The problem comes from the function `insert`, in the `root = leaf` instruction but I can't figure out how can I fix it. I've tried to write the function in a slightly different way. Instead of passing a `leaf`, I tried to pass a value to the insert function and to create a node of the binary tree inside the insert function. It didn't work out.

Can you please me tell me where I am wrong in my code? Thank you

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
struct binaryTree
{
    int data;
    struct binaryTree *left;
    struct binaryTree *right;
};
//the seg fault comes from the function insert
void insert(struct binaryTree *leaf,struct binaryTree *root)
{
    if(root == NULL)
    {   
        //this is the problematic instruction
        root = leaf;//construct the tree if it has not been constructed before
        root->left = NULL;
        root->right = NULL;
    }
    else if(leaf->data > root->data)
    {
        insert(leaf, root->right);
    }
    else if(leaf->data < root->data)
        insert(leaf,root->left);
    else
    {
        printf("The element is in the tree already.\n");
    }
}

void print(struct binaryTree *root)
{
    printf("-------Print--------\n");
    if(root == NULL) return;
    print(root->left);
    printf("%d\n", root->data);
    print(root->right);
}
void createNode(int value,struct binaryTree *node)
{
    printf("-------CreateNode--------\n");
    node = malloc(sizeof(struct binaryTree));
    node->data = value;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
}
void destroy(struct binaryTree *root)
{
    if(root != NULL)
    {
        destroy(root->right);
        destroy(root->left);
        free(root);
    }
}
int main()
{
    struct binaryTree *root = NULL,*a,*b,*c;
    createNode(42,a);
    createNode(13,b);
    createNode(20,c);
    insert(a,root);
    insert(b,root);
    insert(c,root);
    print(root);
    destroy(root);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are passing uninitialized and having indeterminate value `a` to `insert` and trying to dereference it in `root->left = NULL;`. Too bad...

Comment: How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Someone could do it for you, but it would be *far better* if you learned how to do it yourself.  Add `printf()` statements to help trace the order of what is happening and with what values.  Or compile with debug information and run the program under a debugger where you can single step, examine variables, etc.

Comment: The solution is in K&R http://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/Kernighan-Ritchie/C-Programming-Ebook.pdf page 141

Comment: I see you tried to initialize `a` using `createNode`, but it won't work because the argument `node` will be destroyed on returning the function and it won't affect local variables of the caller. Use pointers to modify caller's local variables. I guess you should also use same technique in `insert()`.

Comment: It was with a lot of printf-s that I found the problem instruction. The problem is that I cannot understand what proveks the segmentation fault. Can you please explain me?
In my view, all of the variables are initialised since root= NULL and I have created nodes for *a,*b,*c

Comment: No, `a`, `b` and `c` is NOT initialized as there are no initializer for them.

Comment: You created nodes for `a`, `b` and `c`, then throwed them away.

Comment: Using the value of uninitialized non-static variables, which have indeterminate values, invokes *undefined behavior*. It may cause crash, and may not cause crash.

Comment: Ok, thank you, initializing a,b and c fixed the issue! 
However, what I can't understand is that in the code I submitted I was manipulating pointers to binaryTree. So in my view, when calling  createNode(42,a) I think manipulating the address of a in the function createNode. In other words, a and node should point to the same physical address. Where am I mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

**The problem:**

At the beginning of `main()`, `root` is NULL and `a` is untitialised.

The problem is that `createNode(42,a);` will create and allocate a node, but it's address will be lost.  Only the local parameter `node` will be set by this function and lost forever as soon as it returns.  This value will not be copied to `a`, which hence remain unitialized.

Then you try to `instert(a, root)`:  `a` is still an unitialised pointer and `root` is still NULL.  The first thing that will hapen in `insert()` is that you'll copy the unitialised pointer into `root`, and then you dereference this invalid pointer by trying to set some structure members to NULL.  That causes the segmentation fault !

**How to solve it:**

Make sure that `createNode()` returns the value:

```
struct binaryTree *createNode(int value)
{
    printf("-------CreateNode--------\n");
    struct binaryTree *node = malloc(sizeof(struct binaryTree));
    node->data = value;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    return node; 
}
```

and change min accordingly:

```
a = createNode (42); 
...
```

You then have a similar problem in `insert()`, with the `root` argument. You could here do a similar technique, by rewriting your function:

```
struct binaryTree *insert(struct binaryTree *leaf,struct binaryTree *root) {...}
```

But it requries a little bit more gynmnastics as with `createNode()`.

I propose you therefore another alternative, passing as argument a pointer to a root pointer: this pemits you to change the value of the root poniter

```
void insert(struct binaryTree *leaf,struct binaryTree **root)  // pointer to pointer
{
    if(*root == NULL)
    {   
        //this is the problematic instruction
        *root = leaf;//construct the tree if it has not been constructed before
        (*root)->left = NULL;
        (*root)->right = NULL;
    }
    else if(leaf->data > (*root)->data)
    {
        insert(leaf, &root->right);
    }
    else if(leaf->data < (*root)->data)
        insert(leaf,&root->left);
    else
    {
        printf("The element is in the tree already.\n");
    }
}
```

In main you'd then call it:

```
insert(a,&root);
```

Comment: Can you explain why the address allocated by createNode(a,42) will be lost? I thought that a and node would have the same address since they're both pointers.

Comment: The argument is passed by value:  this means that the original pointer a is copied into a local argument (node), and then remains unchainde.  WHen you write node=..., it only affects the local parameter.  If you pass a pointer that points already to a valid regiion, you could in the function modify the region you point at, but not the pointer itself.

Comment: Thank you! I understood my error, I thought I was passing the argument by reference but apparently it was not the case.
In the solution you proposed for the insert function, it seems to me there is an error when you call insert(leaf,&root->left)  and insert(leaf,&root->right).